# Как на C# узнать последнюю установленную версию .Net Framework?И возможен ли запуск приложения с более новым .Net Fw?

Tags: c#, .net

Как на C# узнать последнюю установленную версию .Net Framework?И возможен ли запуск приложения с более новым .Net Fw?
Запустится ли оно вообще или возникнет ошибка в момент выполнения,когда будут отсутствовать модули в данной версии фреймворка?
Хотелось бы,что б при первой загрузке приложение узнавало версию фреймворка,и если она старая,то скачать новую версию и установить.
Эту проверку может сделать программа только под старым фреймворком или можно писать приложение,например,на 4.6.2（когда у клиента изначально таковой не установлен）?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С более новым можно. Microsoft старается не нарушать обратную совместимость скомпилированного кода, так что проблем быть не должно.

По поводу того, как выяснить, какие версии установлены, вот [официальный пример от Microsoft с кодом](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#net_d).

---

Если на системе установлена более новая версия фреймворка, то приложение запустится. При компиляции вы всегда указываете, какая версия фреймворка вам нужна. Под более старой версией программа, разумеется, не запустится, поэтому сценарий «что б при первой загрузке приложение узнавало версию фреймворка, и если она старая,то скачать новую версию и установить» не сработает. Хуже того, юзер, который запустит программу, скорее всего не администратор, и скорее всего программа, запущенная с его правами не сможет установить нужную версию .NET.

Вам нужен инсталлятор, который при инсталляции проверит и при необходимости поставит нужный фреймворк. Точно так же он сможет скопировать программу в Program Files, где программам и полагается быть.

Comment: но для этого проверяющая программа должна запуститься под имеющийся фреймфорк, а если она написана на новом - разве запустится на старом?

Comment: @Grundy: Разумеется. Но вопрос был ведь не «как запустить программу, если .NET не установлен» или «если фреймворк старее чем надо».

Comment: @Grundy: А то, что хочет ТС делать при первой загрузке, это называется словом «инсталлятор».

Comment: _Эту проверку может сделать программа только под старым фреймворком или можно писать приложение,например,на 4.6.2（когда у клиента изначально таковой не установлен?_ - нет ответа на этот вопрос :)

Comment: @Grundy: Дописал :) Спасибо за помощь!